# Json file not exporting correctly from python string array in a for loop

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export

i am making a website scraper that scrapes the websites and looks for specific keywords in a website and if it finds the keyword it would either call the website to productive or unproductive and then it would export that info into a json file so i can get it with c# later but the problem is that the json exporting method is not exporting correctly and i am new to both pyhton and json.

i have tried everything and every syntax there is but nothing seems to be working as i want it to be.

this is my python code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# this scraps the websites that i give it
def scrap_website():

    pages = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHI2NIaNrGk',
            'https://aljazeera.com', 'https://www.svt.se']

    for site in pages:
        page = requests.get(site)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        if 'Game' in soup.getText():
            is_productive = False
            json_map = {}
            json_map["websiteLink"] = site
            json_map["isProductive"] = is_productive
            json_text = json.dumps(json_map)

        else:
            is_productive = True

            json_map = {}
            json_map["websiteLink"] = site
            json_map["isProductive"] = is_productive
            json_text = json.dumps(json_map)

        data = []
        data.append(json_text)
        with open('data\\data.json', 'a') as json_file:
             json.dump(data, json_file, indent=2, separators=(
                 ", ", "  "), sort_keys=True)


scrap_website()
```

this is the json code that i am getting

```
[
  "{\"websiteLink\": \"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHI2NIaNrGk\", \"isProductive\": false}"
][
  "{\"websiteLink\": \"https://aljazeera.com\", \"isProductive\": true}"
][
  "{\"websiteLink\": \"https://www.svt.se\", \"isProductive\": true}"
]
```

Comment: append to array the dicts, not the strings, and then serialize all the data

Comment: also shift `with` statement from the loop, and create `list` outside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all nodes in the same json, declaring an array and go to adding each website as node of the array so:

Declare array before than loop

```
json_map = []
```

For each website

```
site_node = {}

site_node["websiteLink"] = site

site_node["isProductive"] = is_productive

json_map.append(site_node)
```

Finally save the json outside of the loop

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as outFile:

    json.dump(json_map, outFile)
```

After you can load the json array and loop it with a simple for

Comment: thanks but now it is not writing anything and its giving me this error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: use append  instead add

Comment: sorry but still not working it gave the same error but insted it was 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'  if you like you can check the whole thing at https://github.com/abodsakah/unproductive-scraper

Comment: @abodsakka you redefine json_map from list into map inside the if block